# BigQuery return all matches of regular expression

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, re2

In Big Query, when I do a regular expression search, it only returns the first match/occurrence.

Is there any way to return *all* matches, concatenated? something like `GROUP_CONCAT` maybe?

`REGEXP_EXTRACT(body, r"(\w+ )")`

Answer (score 8):

In Standard SQL that was recently introduced being supported by BigQuery - you can try as below

```
SELECT 
  body,
  (SELECT STRING_AGG(word) FROM words.word) AS words
FROM (
  SELECT 
    body, REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(body, r'(\w+)') AS word
  FROM (
    SELECT 'abc xyz qwerty asd' AS body UNION ALL
    SELECT 'zxc dfg 345' AS body
  )
) words
```

Don't forget to uncheck `Use Legacy SQL` checkbox under <kbd>Show Options</kbd>
See more details on [REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/functions-and-operators#regexp_extract_all) and [STRING_AGG](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/functions-and-operators#string_agg)

---

If you are stuck with what is now in BigQuery called legacy SQL - you can try something like below

```
SELECT 
  body, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(SPLIT(body, ' ')) AS words
FROM 
  (SELECT 'abc xyz qwerty asd' AS body),
  (SELECT 'zxc dfg 345' AS body)
```

I understand, this is not necessarily exactly what you need - but might help

---

Another approach with BigQuery legacy SQL that more suited to cases where you have to use regex.
For example - assume you need extract only numbers from body
Idea is to nuke anything but numbers from body using [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#regularexpressionfunctions) and then apply above described [SPLIT()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#split) + [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#group_concat)

```
SELECT 
  body, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(body, r'(\D)+', ':'), ':')) AS words
FROM 
  (SELECT 'abc 123 xyz 543 qwerty asd' AS body),
  (SELECT '987zxc 123 dfg 345' AS body)
```